# Find Units of each sensors in CMMotionManager in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, logging, uiaccelerometer, magnitude

There is any in build method to know the Units of each sensor values?

Im trying to find the value for Acceleration Magnitude. We have any inbuild method to find it out or i can follow the following formula?

```
(√(Accelx2+Accely2+Accelz2))/ 9.80665
```

Like wise i would like to log all the value when button action is triggered. Currently im getting only last value.

Thanks in advance